# How to deal with places datas without storing them?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Google Maps API TOS don't allow to store in a database any other information than the ID or Reference of a place. So, should we make a new API query every time we need a detail information such as city or country?

If for example I use the API to get the current location of a user through an autocomplete field. I only store the ID or reference? I can not store the country, the city in order to then make queries in my database to know all users from a city or country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely "store" the extra country/city information for the current session. That's not what Google's terms of service are trying to prevent. They just don't want you to store their data in a database permanently.

Comment: Ok, but I don't need this info in the session. I need to keep this information somewhere to be accessible everytime from any visitor.

Comment: Then store it in a cookie/local storage, like an extended session, instead of in your database. That way it can still expire or be removed by the user. Google TOS just don't want you becoming an alternative source for their API, which isn't your intention here.

Comment: Sorry but I think you don't understand my need, probably because of my poor english ;) Imagine I want to display on a page a table with a list of countries and the corresponding total of users from each country. I just can't do this if I only have an ID or a Reference in my database right ?

Comment: Oh. I don't think that's allowed. See section 10.1.3 of TOS at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_1_3. I think your case falls under "exporting, writing, or saving the Content to a third party’s location-based platform or service."